# How do I get my Epiphany buttons back?

Tags: epiphany

Running Epiphany on ubuntu 12.04 on an iMac G5 powerpc.

The only button I have is a "Web" button inside the browser and a wheel on the far right corner.

I can't for example set a home page, unless there is a terminal command to do so.

I don't have a view button either...

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is, unfortunately, a feature of Gnome 3.4 and above.

See the release notes here: http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.4/#rnusers.gnome-3-applications

I've searched hard and haven't found a way to restore the old style menu bars.

So far the Gnome developers have, in their infinite wisdom, managed to destroy Epiphany, Baobab, Nautilus and others in this way. From a usability perspective it's a complete disaster - I now need to click, move the mouse and click again just to close a window! I shudder to think what "innovations" they'll come up with next..

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "problem." It is the new design of the web browser. This is simply how Epiphany is designed to be now. If you wish to express any issues you have with it, the best place to do so, is [the upstream bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=epiphany).

Comment: OK, then how do I set a home page on Epiphany?

There was no mention of this being so on the Epiphany home page, all documentation pointed to buttons I don't have like Edit and View.

Comment: Perhaps the web site you were looking at for Epiphany is also out of date, and needs a bug filed against it. Looking at the configuration schema for Epiphany, there is no home page setting any more.

Comment: Like Google.com sis out of date.

Why on earth is there no more home page setting? And wher do I disable add-ons/plugins?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Google.com doesn't know anything about Epiphany, or if a web page is current or not. I'm not an Epiphany developer. If you want to complain to them, follow the link I gave in my answer, to open a bug report.